# What is the advantage of internal only elbs over secured public elbs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

I'm a little unclear on the advantage of internal only ELBs. I could restrict access to my public ELBs with security groups and I have the advantage of allowing public traffic by merely adjusting the security group.

Is the advantage just being absolutely sure no public traffic can hit the ELB? Is it purely for that fail safe kind of thing or is there something here I am missing that I can do with internal ELB but not external ELB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct.

In reality, you could run an entire AWS solution in public subnets, using Security Groups to protect the resources.

However, many companies use traditional firewalls to add protection to their infrastructure and this requires separating resources into public/private subnets. (Security Groups, on the other hand, can operate at the resource-level.)

As a result, companies typically carry-over these practices into the cloud. Adding multiple layers of security is good because it limits the potential damage from possible failures or misconfigurations. However, the choice is entirely yours to make.

Comment: I suspect OP has overlooked the fact that internal ELBs don't result in the additional costs that result from going out the Internet Gateway and coming back in to an outside-facing ELB, which is $0.01 out and $0.01 back in per GB, or more, depending on region, and more than that if a NAT Gateway is involved on one side.  Internal traffic to external-facing ELBs uses substantially more network infrastructure, unnecessarily, and has an accompanying cost.  Also, source security group context has no meaning across an IGW.